# Purpose of "email" in sharing link's question

Tags: support, sharing

I just found out that when we would like to share our question there is Google+, Twitter and Facebook, all working fine. But what's the need of `email` in this image?

It's not doing anything.

[image]

I am using google chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Do you have an email client? It has a `mailto:` href.. You can email the question

Comment: Since when do we close support questions with "can no longer be reproduced"?

Comment: Just to be clear: this repro-ed for me. It is a local configuration/setup issue though, not an issue SE can control or fix (unless it chooses to implement that email link differently which isn't going to happen, not even in the next 6 to 8 years).

Answer (score 3):

It's a plain `mailto:` hyperlink. It should open a *New mail* window in your default mail client.

Possibly the window wasn't placed on the foreground automatically, I know sometimes Outlook does that.

Comment: Don't you think it's bad for stackoverflow to rely on user's default mail client. If they didn't have that

Comment: It's a standard web practice since... forever, I think? What do you propose they do, detect that you use MySuperFunEmailService and automatically navigate you to the correct webpage?

Comment: What would be the alternative? If you don't have e-mail, then how do you want to share via email. You also can't share on FB unless you have an FB account.

Comment: OP could expect that SE runs their own email service. So on clicking the link you get an form where you enter the email address of your victim and then spam them with mails with links to SE posts.... *I'm only wildly guessing here*

Comment: @rene hehehe
 I am just thinking that like clicking on google+ takes us to google page just like that clicking on email would have open new mail window.  If user didn't have default mail client available then it should notify.

Comment: Well, not quite forever. Looks like `mailto` wasn't defined until 1998. :-) But yeah, nothing else makes any sense. There's no other way to guess what mail client I want to use.

Comment: @Lokesh That would be the job of your browser, not the webpage.

Comment: @Stijn I am using google chrome `Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)` do I need to make some changes in setting to enable that ?

Comment: @Lokesh I've no idea, sorry. I don't even know if it's possible to configure your browser like that. Anyway, we're getting pretty off-topic here from the original question.

Comment: My Chrome doesn't handle mailto either. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler or search on superuser.com.

Comment: @rene thank you for the link

Comment: Just to be complete, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17517600) explains what is going on. If I use firefox or Edge, clicking the email link starts Chrome for me. When you click on that link from Chrome it will do the same but as Chrome is already running it will appears as if it does nothing. This behavior is probably the left over of a once allowed option to use gmail as your default email client. After disabling that you're left with this confusion. Edge pops-up a dialog, offering an option to switch the default app for the `mailto:` protocol.

Comment: `mailto:` links work just fine on `Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)` for me.  I click the link, and it opens Outlook 2016 and creates a new email with the shared link included in the body of the email, ready for me to enter a "to" address.

Answer (score -1):

> The link opens a client's e-mail system and begins a new email
>   message.

There is more info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx) and an example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto).

Comment: No, it doesn't do that on Chrome.

Comment: @rene - Yes, it does.  It works with Chrome for me.  Perhaps you don't have an email client program installed on your computer?  (Outlook, for example -- the desktop application, not the website).

If you use webmail like gmail or hotmail (instead of a client), there are Chrome add-ins you can get so `mailto:` links will be handled with your webmail client.  [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailto-for-gmail/dgkkmcknielgdhebimdnfahpipajcpjn?hl=en-GB) is a Chrome add-in.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. And I know how to register a protocol handler and verify if it works. It is a local setup issue. That is the problem the OP faces as well. Your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: Correct; my answer explains the purpose of the `email` link in the OP's included image, and illustrates that if the link is not working for the OP, it is _not_ an issue with Stack Exchange.